# Is a Transit visa required by a US citizen with an overnight Taoyuan Intl. (TPE) layover?

Tags: us-citizens, transit-visas, tpe

I'm a US passport holder. My flight lands at Taoyuan Intl. (TPE) airport at 6:55 pm and does not fly out till 4:20 pm  next day to Tokyo with a layover of 21 hours. I will be traveling on Chinese airlines from Manila to Tokyo.

Do I need a transit visa?

Is it okay for me to leave the airport to explore and come back next morning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No as a US citizen you don't need a visa to stay or enter in Taiwan Taoyuan Intl. (TPE) airport. Answer is from official [Travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/taiwan.html) :

> "If you wish to enter Taiwan as a tourist or short-term visitor (less
>   than 90 days), you do not need a visa. To enter Taiwan, you need:
>
> - No extensions or changes of status are permitted.
> - Your U.S. passport must be valid throughout your intended length of    stay
> - you must have a confirmed return or onward air ticket.

Similarly [Visa Policy Of Taiwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Taiwan) and [Timatic](http://www.qatarairways.com/pk/en/visa-and-passport-requirements.page) confirms the same:

> National USA (US)               /Embarkation Philippines (PH) Transit
>   Chinese Taipei (TW)     /Destination Japan (JP) ALSO CHECK DESTINATION
>   INFORMATION BELOW
>
> Chinese Taipei (TW)
>
> VISA NOT REQUIRED.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Transit hotel is only available for Eva Airways (BR) and   China Airlines (CI) passengers. Additional Information:
>
> - Former nationals of China (People's Rep.)

Further as you are traveling on China Airlines, you can also avail [Free half day tour](https://www.china-airlines.com/us/en/discover/news/press-release/Taiwan-Free-half-day-tour.html) as a US citizen. Passengers with 7-24 hour layover before their next connecting flight can participate in this free tour. Details regarding program and policy can be obtained from this website:

[Taiwan Free half-day tour](https://www.china-airlines.com/us/en/discover/news/press-release/Taiwan-Free-half-day-tour.html)

Comment: Good answer, but maybe it would be good to have a link from the Taiwan government instead of the US?  After all, it is Taiwan that makes these rules.

Comment: @NateEldredge ok updating answer

Comment: An answer from the US Department of State is NEVER an "official" answer when it comes to the visa requirements of other countries!!